# connect oracle database in netbeans

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

i am trying to connect oracle database to netbeans. I followed instruction that given in https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/oracle-db.html .
I fulfilled all the steps that given site.
but when i try to connect database by using servlet page i got an error.

error is given below,

> Error Occured : Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor The Connection descriptor used by the client was: localhost:1521:XE [kavindu on KAVINDU]

I have no idea, what i next do,

My servlet code is given below,

```
 protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String customer_id = request.getParameter("customer_id");
    String f_name = request.getParameter("f_name");
    String l_name = request.getParameter("l_name");
    String mobile_no = request.getParameter("mobile_no");
    String address = request.getParameter("address");

 try {
         //loading driver 

        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

        //creating connection with the database 
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE [kavindu on KAVINDU]","kavindu","123456");

        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into COMPACT_DISK values(?,?,?,?,?)");


        ps.setString(1, customer_id);
        ps.setString(2, f_name);
        ps.setString(3, l_name);
        ps.setString(4, mobile_no);
        ps.setString(5, address);
        int i = ps.executeUpdate();

 if (i > 0) {
            //out.println("Compact disk successfully inserted");
            RequestDispatcher d = request.getRequestDispatcher("new.html");
            d.forward(request, response);
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException | ServletException | IOException se) {
        out.println("Error Occured : \n" + se.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}

 @Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

  */
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}// </editor-fold>

}
```

Comment: Remove the `[kavindu on KAVINDU]` part from the JDBC URL. Nowhere does the tutorial state you have to enter that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the database SID is correct, I think that's the problem.